# FTFGAG Isomorphism to Invariant Factor Decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm seeking an isomorphism (or algorithm for constructing one in general) between the group of units modulo n (particularly, n=the product of primes 5, 7, 11, $\ldots$), and it's unique isomorphism class (as guaranteed by the Fundamental Theorem) in terms of it's invariant factors.

To give an example:  $U(35)$=$(Z_{35})^*$=$(Z/35Z)^*$.

$U(35) \cong U(5) \times U(7)$.  This iso is clear: $\phi(x)=($x mod 5, x mod 7$)$.

Now, $U(p) \cong Z_{p-1}$, and so we have $U(35) \cong Z_4 \times Z_6$, but this is not the unique isomorphism class, rather by the Fund. Th., $U(35) \cong Z_2 \times Z_{12}$.  It is not at all clear to me how to construct this isomorphism explicitly (the natural choice of (x mod 2, x mod 12) doesn't work).

Likewise, $U(385) \cong U(5) \times U(7) \times U(11) \cong Z_4 \times Z_6 \times Z_{10} \cong Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_{60}$.

And one more, $U(5005) \cong U(5) \times U(7) \times U(11) \times U(13)\cong Z_4 \times Z_6 \times Z_{10} \times Z_{12} \cong Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_{12} \times Z_{60}$.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: There are sort of two separate isomorphisms you need to put together.  First the isomorphism $U(p) \cong Z_{p-1}$ requires you to find a primitive root mod $p$, i.e., a generator for $U(p)$.  For instance, $3$ generates $U(7)$.  The second isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/35\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ comes from the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: Maybe all you're really looking for is $Z_4 \times Z_6 \cong Z_4 \times Z_2 \times Z_3 \cong Z_2 \times Z_4 \times Z_3 \cong Z_2 \times Z_{12}$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.